# Law of large numbers applicability

Tags: probability

Can you define a series of $(X_n)$ so that for every such n, we get $X_n\sim\mathsf{Geo}\left(\frac{1}{7n}\right)$ and for a constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$, such that 

$$\displaystyle{\mathbb{P}\left[ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X_n}{n} = c \right] = 1}$$ 
if so, find $c$.

I believe there is not such $c$ but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic function $\phi_n$ of $X_n$ is given by  $\phi_n(t)=\frac {p_n} {1-(1-p_n)e^{it}}$ where $p_n=\frac1  {7n}$. From  this it is easy to see that the characteristic function of $\frac {X_n} n $ tends to  $0$ at every point other than $0$. Hence this sequence does not converge in distribution. In particular it does not converge with probability $1$.

Comment: Thank you.
the characteristic function $\phi_n$ is the function using the central limit theorem?
and you divide it by n, and then perform the limit?

Comment: Characteristic function of of $X$ is defined as $Ee^{itX}$. @shahaf137

Comment: Great, thank you!